# How can I write a thin wrapper component with the same tag as its child

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'll use a contrived example below to describe what I'm (sort of) trying to accomplish.

Let's say I wanted to log something to the console when an Angular Material2 progress spinner is rendered or removed.

The wrapper:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-spinner',
  template: '<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>' // This would be the OTHER mat-spinner
})
export class LoggingSpinnerComponent() implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Spinner rendered");
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("Spinner destroyed");
  }

}
```

Notice that I use `mat-spinner` for the `LoggingSpinnerComponent`'s selector, but also, I'm *using* `mat-spinner` inside it's template.

Obviously this is not going to work.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Can I "namespace" the `MaterialProgressSpinnerModule` so that I can make use of something like `<original-mat-spinner>` in this outer component's template?

---

#### Background.

What I'm really trying to do is write a tracker that keeps a record of how long users see spinners in the wild.  And, I'll make a dashboard to highlight which parts of my application are suffering from excessive spinner time (This won't necessarily be tied to the performance of one specific API, hence my interest in this wrapper).

The reason I want to use a wrapper with the same selector (mat-spinner) is so I can swap out `MatProgressSpinnerModule` and use `LoggingSpinnerModule` instead, without having to touch any code otherwise.

It would also make it easier to remove the `LoggingSpinnerModule` in the future if it turns out to be a failed experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a template, so you can use a directive rather than a component:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-spinner'
})
export class LoggingSpinnerDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Spinner rendered");
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("Spinner destroyed");
  }

}
```